Ubuntu - Basic Add new Admin User
Can someone make a post that explains, with a new install of ubuntu, shell command(s) how to create a new "admin" user that is the same as what you get when you use GUI.
sudo useradd bob -d /home/jerewis --groups admin
sudo usermod bob -aG sudo 

Lots of posts about how to create use but what you get is a way different shell and enviroment then if you use GUI.  Which is rediculous.
Many other distributions this is just simple. It copies over /etc/skel  which has basic user profile of bash and structure.  If you add them to "sudo" or "wheel" etc... they can then run elevated commands.  I just tested this again on 24.04 and gave up and  used the GUI to create the user as it was too many yak layers to get a basic admin account created.
Thanks...

Any question needs to have what version of Ubuntu you are using? Also what have you already tried? What research have you done?

Related: New user created from command line has missing features and What is the difference between adduser and useradd?

Open a terminal and become a super-user
  exec sudo -i
  
  adduser bob
  

Enter the new password:
Re-enter the new password:
Enter the new value, or press ENTER to use the default value:
Is the information correct? [Y/n] Y
Or:
  exec sudo -i
  
  useradd -m bob
  
  passwd bob

Enter the new password:
Re-enter the new password:
passwd: password updated successfully
Add the user to sudoers:
 nano -c /etc/sudoers
 

Leave it like that:
 # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
 %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
 bob ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Ctrl + O - save
Ctrl + X - close
  exit

 

